# How can I add gunicorn so that I can deploy my flask application with docker-compose?

Tags: python, docker, flask, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I already can run the docker-compose with flask. However, I really don't know how can I add gunicorn in the command so that it can be used. I already added it in my requirements.txt file. Here I can show you my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  waitfordb:
        image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
        depends_on:
            mysql:
              condition: service_healthy
        environment:
            MYSQL_PORT: "3306"
        command: mysql:3306
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "12345678"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: flaskmysql
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysql -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e 'SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables' $$MYSQL_DATABASE"
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 20
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      waitfordb:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: /flask/app/server.py
    
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${MYSQL_HOST}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DB: ${MYSQL_DB}
    volumes:
      - ./:/flask
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git python3-dev gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
```

Server.py file

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return jsonify({'result': "Fire detection app"})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=False, host="0.0.0.0")
```

If anyone knows where I can replace the command so that it can get all the traffic from port 5000. So that I can deploy it in an ec2 instance for a presentation that I need to run. Thanks!

Comment: How would you normally run GUnicorn, without Docker?  Make that command be the Dockerfile's `CMD` line (and delete the buggy `ENTRYPOINT` line and the Compose `command:` override).

Answer (score 0):

I have a flask app with gunicorn, docker and docker-compose and it works like this:

Dockerfile

user.app is the location in the directory and create_app() is defined in that file.  In your case replace ENTRYPOINT with CMD.

```
Other info here ...
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 120 --access-logfile - "user.app:create_app()
```

docker-compose

Replace your command: with what is listed below.

```
Other info here...
build:
  context: ./
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
command: >
  gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000
    --timeout 120
    --access-logfile -
    --reload
    "user.app:create_app()
container_name: user
Other info here...
```

Comment: So I need to change my dockerfile with "CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 120 --access-logfile - "user.app:create_app()" this and also my docker-compose command variable?

Comment: My app uses the App Factory pattern.  So I define create_app in my app.py file.  I can't see any of your code such as server.py that you reference.  Look at your server.py file that you reference in the docker-compose to find the comparable def statement to create_app().  If you are using create_app in server.py then try app.server:create_app() in place of user.app:create_app()

Comment: I updated the content so that u can see my server.py. It's just a file that contains all of the endpoints + connections to my MySQL database. You can see the index endpoint and the run method below.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well app may be imported in another file but you can try: app.server:app

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow if my internet gets better. It's so slow that I can't even download a package bigger than 500 MB. Thank you so much for the follow-up.

Comment: I'm getting this error "No module named 'app'"